# job processing from a que of jobs in C

Tags: c, struct, scheduling, priority-queue

Here is a question 
Initially a set of job is given with its job_id, arrival_time (which will be 0) and execution_time. There is a single processor which can be used to execute these jobs. Each job will get a fixed amount of time (say d) to execute in the processor. Once that time duration is over then the next job will get the chance to execute and the current job, if it is not yet completed, will go to the end of the job queue. This job switching time is considered to be negligible. New jobs may also arrive after the job scheduling process is started. In that case the arrival_time is assumed to be greater than 0. Once a new job arrives; it will be added to the job queue. If at any point of time, a new job arrives and also an existing job completed its ‘d’ amount of time in the processor, then first the new job will be added to the job queue and then the existing job will be added to the job queue. Perform the job scheduling and show the status of job scheduling after a certain time instant. Display each job with job_id, arrival_time, execution_time, start_time, finish_time, remaining_time, status (Completed or Not completed).

Below is my implementation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct job{
        int pid;
        int at;
        int et;
        };

//Node for creating a jobq
struct jobq{
        int pid;
        int at;
        int et;
         struct jobq *next;
        };
struct Queue
{
    struct jobq *front, *rear;
};

struct jobq* newNode(int k,int l, int j)
{
    struct jobq *temp = (struct jobq*)malloc(sizeof(struct jobq));
    temp->pid = k;
    temp->at = l;
    temp->et = j;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

// A utility function to create an empty queue
struct Queue *createQueue()
{
    struct Queue *q = (struct Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    q->front = q->rear = NULL;
    return q;
}

void enQueue(struct Queue *q, int k, int l, int j)
{
    // Create a new LL node
    struct jobq *temp = newNode(k,l,j);

    // If queue is empty, then new node is front and rear both
    if (q->rear == NULL)
    {
    q->front = q->rear = temp;
       return;
    }

    // Add the new node at the end of queue and change rear
    q->rear->next = temp;
    q->rear = temp;
}

struct jobq *deQueue(struct Queue *q)
{
    // If queue is empty, return NULL.
    if (q->front == NULL)
       return NULL;

    // Store previous front and move front one node ahead
    struct jobq *temp = q->front;
    q->front = q->front->next;

    // If front becomes NULL, then change rear also as NULL
    if (q->front == NULL)
       q->rear = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void schedule(struct job rec[], struct job rec2[], int n1,int n2,int inst,int tq)
{
        struct Queue *q = createQueue();
        //Putting the jobs with AT=0 into jobq initially.
        for(int a=0 ; a<n1 ; a++)
        {
                enQueue(q , rec[a].pid, rec[a].at, rec[a].et);
        }

        struct jobq *j;
        j = q->front;

        struct ansjob{
                int apid;
                int aat;
                int start;
                int end ;
                int rem;
                int status;
                };

        struct ansjob instance[100];
      int start, end, rem, status,clock=0,i=0;
        while(1)
        {
                if(j->et < tq)
                {
                        start = clock;
                        end = start + j->et;
                        rem = 0 ;
                        clock = clock + j->et;
                        instance[i].apid = j->pid ;
                        instance[i].aat = j->at ;
                        instance[i].start = start ;
                        instance[i].end = end ;
                        instance[i].rem = rem ;
                        instance[i].status = 0 ; //COMPLETED
                        i++;
                        deQueue(q);
                        for(int k=0 ; k<n2 ; k++)
                        {       if(rec2[k].at <= clock)
                                {enQueue(q,rec2[k].pid,rec2[k].at,rec2[k].et);}
                        }

                        if(clock==(inst))
                        {break;}
                        else if(clock<(inst))
                        {
                          j = q->front;
                          continue;
                        }
                        else if(clock>(inst))
                        {break;}
                }
                        else if(j->et == tq)
                {
                          start = clock;
                          end = start + tq;
                          rem = 0 ;
                          clock = clock + tq ;
                          instance[i].apid = j->pid ;
                          instance[i].aat = j->at ;
                          instance[i].start = start ;
                          instance[i].end = end ;
                          instance[i].rem = rem ;
                          instance[i].status = 0 ;//COMPLETED
                          i++;
                          deQueue(q);
                          for(int k=0 ; k<n2 ; k++)
                        {     if(rec2[k].at <= clock)
                                {enQueue(q,rec2[k].pid,rec2[k].at,rec2[k].et);}
                          }
                          if(clock==(inst))
                          {break;}
                          else if(clock < (inst))
                          {
                          j = q->front;
                          continue;
                          }
                          else if(clock > (inst))
                          {break;}
                }

                else
                {
                        j->et = j->et -tq;
                        start = clock ;
                        end = -1 ;
                        rem = j->et ;
                        clock = clock + tq ;
                        instance[i].apid = j->pid ;
                        instance[i].aat = j->at ;
                        instance[i].start = start ;
                        instance[i].end = end ;
                        instance[i].rem = rem ;
                        instance[i].status = 1 ;//NOT COMPLETED
                        i++;
                        deQueue(q);
                        for(int k=0 ; k<n2 ; k++)
                        {       if(rec2[k].at <= clock)
                                {enQueue(q,rec2[k].pid,rec2[k].at,rec2[k].et);}
                        }
                        enQueue(q,j->pid,j->at,j->et);
                        if(clock==(inst))
                        {break;}
                        else if(clock < (inst))
                        {
                          j = q->front;
                          continue;
                        }
                        else if(clock > (inst))
                        {break; }


                }
        }
                                                                         printf("\n--------JOB STATUS------------\n");
        printf("PID\tAT\tSTART\tEND\tREM\tSTATUS\n");

        for(int s=0 ; s<i ; s++)
        {
                printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t",instance[s].apid ,instance[s].aat, instance[s].start, instance[s].end, instance[s].rem);
                if(instance[s].status == 0)
                {printf("COMPLETED");}
                else if(instance[s].status == 1)
                {printf("NOT COMPLETED");}
                printf("\n");
        }

}



void main()
{
        int tq,n,n1;
        printf("Enter the processor alloted time= ");
        scanf("%d" , &tq);
        printf("\nEnter the initial set of jobs at time = 0");
        printf("\nEnter number of jobs");
        scanf("%d" ,&n);
        struct job record[n] ;
        for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
                printf("PID = ");
                scanf("%d" , &record[i].pid);
                printf("Arrival Time = ");
                scanf("%d" , &record[i].at);
                printf("Execution Time = ");
                scanf("%d" , &record[i].et);
        }

        char flag[4];
        printf("Any more jobs at later time :");
        scanf("%s" , flag);
        struct job latrec[n1];
        if((strcmp(flag , "YES")) == 0)
        {       printf("\nEnter number of jobs");
                scanf("%d" ,&n1);

                for(int j=0 ; j<n1 ; j++)
                {
                printf("PID = ");
                                                                                        printf("PID = ");
                scanf("%d" , &latrec[j].pid);
                printf("Arrival Time = ");
                scanf("%d" , &latrec[j].at);
                printf("Execution Time = ");
                scanf("%d" , &latrec[j].et);
                }
        }

        else if((strcmp(flag , "NO")) == 0)
        {}
        int instance ;
        printf("Enter the time instance for displaying the job scheduling result:");
        scanf("%d" , &instance);
        schedule(record, latrec, n, n1,instance, tq);

}
```

Now when I execute this code

```
Enter the processor alloted time= 3

Enter the initial set of jobs at time = 0
Enter number of jobs6
PID = 1
Arrival Time = 3
Execution Time = 24
PID = 2
Arrival Time = 6
Execution Time = 10
PID = 3
Arrival Time = 5
Execution Time = 12
PID = 4
Arrival Time = 8
Execution Time = 20
PID = 5
Arrival Time = 2
Execution Time = 40
PID = 6
Arrival Time = 1
Execution Time = 22
Any more jobs at later time :no
Enter the time instance for displaying the job scheduling result:7

--------JOB STATUS------------
PID     AT      START   END     REM     STATUS
1       3       0       -1      21      NOT COMPLETED
2       6       3       -1      7       NOT COMPLETED
3       5       6       -1      9       NOT COMPLETED
```

I am not able to verify the results if this is the correct output as per the question. Can some one help me to

1) verify the result if the output is wrong then what went wrong in my implementation is what I would like to know. 
2) Is there a better way to approach such problem I mean a better algorithm than the one in implementation if yes then how to approach such problems to reduce the complexity may be in some other language other than C some inbuilt functions exist to implement the same, I know a little bit of python and basics of Java but I am more comfortable in C.

Comment: That doesn't seem correct. If job 2 didn't arrive until time index 6, then it couldn't have started at time index 3. And job 3 arrived at time 5, so it probably should have been inserted into the queue ahead of job 2.

Comment: Before you start changing your code, I would suggest that you create a smaller set of jobs (perhaps the first three in your list), and work the exercise *by hand* with pencil and paper. Or, if you must, in a spreadsheet. Write down each step that you take to figure out what job comes next, and how things are inserted into and removed from the queue. Once you're satisfied that you have the correct answer, figure out how you would write code to do the same thing. The code you have right now is complicated and confusing, meaning you don't fully understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Come to think of it, job 6 arrived at time index 1, so it should have started first. And job 5 arrived at time index 2. It looks like your jobs should start in the order 6, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4.